# How does Stacking Enchantments work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, I have noticed that when trying to combine enchantments with Equipment/Books, occasionally, the enchantments will not be applied, simply because there are too many enchantments on an item.

For example, I might have 2 books. One with, say, Unbreaking, Silk Touch, and Mending, and another with Protection, Aqua Affinity, and Frost Walker. In this example, (I'm not sure if these sets of enchantments *will* combine - will test this later) they will drop off an enchantment due to the "cap" of enchantments on an item.

I know that some Enchantments make others redundant (I.e. Silk Touch and Fortune, or vice-versa), so they will not combine. Others simply overlap - like the same enchantment of different levels (Unbreaking 3 overwrites Unbreaking 2). And obviously, enchantments that cannot be applied to equipment will simply not be, like Aqua Affinity on a pair of boots. However, after several tests, I haven't been able to figure out how the enchantments are dropped when combining them, outside of these parameters.

Is there any way I can determine which enchantment I will lose when combining books? And will this affect Curses too (Curse of the Vanishing/Curse of Binding)?

Comment: Please test the example you have provided and add the result to your answer. If you apply both the books on a pickaxe then the protection, aqua affinity and frost walker will disappear since they cannot be applied to a pickaxe. If you apply it to boots, the silk touch and Aqua affinity will disappear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Only the enchantments that are compatible with the item will apply, regardless of how many they are, however the costs may increase the more enchantments you apply, the better they are, and the more combinations you do.** And, also as you said, certain enchantments won't stack, except by Creative Mode means. Examples are multiple type of Protection, Silk Touch and Fortune, etc.

*Note that if there are conflicting enchantments, those on the item placed in the first slot of an Anvil will replace the ones of the other item's. Those on the item in the second slot will be erased.*

***See [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#Summary_of_enchantments) a complete list of the enchantments, and where they can be applied, and how.***

Comment: And how it works on (book + book -> book) ? Because on THAT is this question.

Comment: Every enchantment on the books will combine, except the conflicting ones, where those on the book in the first slot are prioritised, and those on the second erased. @AntoineHejlík

Comment: So after some testing, it turns out my initial experience was incorrect - this is how it works. I tested this by combining enchanted books in a crafting bench. Interestingly enough, you can combine a total of 21 Enchantments (including both curses) into [one book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nfW6.png), and at maximum level enchantments (Efficiency 5, Unbreaking 3, etc.) it costs 4,194,292 level of experience.